# Adaptive thumbnail div which responsive to screen size

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a list of thumbnail images which when you resize the browser screen they all adapt nicely and keep the same height and width.

I need to add in a thumbnail for when there is no image, with a centerd icon, however when i resize the browser the div doesnt expand the same way as the images.

This is designed for mobile screens, but i would like it to have the same behavious as the images.

What am i missing in the code, im guessings its a css issue to do with height or margin / percentage values?

I have a demo with all the code i have done: -

http://jsfiddle.net/zM5SG/1/

```
.gallery li a.addImage {
display: block;
margin: 7px 5px 0 5px;
border: 1px dotted #aaa;
background-color: #ddd;
min-height: 58px;   
}

.test{
   background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-   design/mini/24/Delete-icon.png") no-repeat scroll /*1px -109px*/ center transparent; 
   display: block; width:24px; height:24px; text-align:center; 
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 15%; margin-bottom: 15%;
}
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the most elegant way, but couldn't you just replace the "empty space" with an image that looks blank? so it would resize the same as the other images?

Answer (score 0):

For the class test instead of `width:24px` give `width:inherit`. So the new style will be

```
.test{
   background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-   design/mini/24/Delete-icon.png") no-repeat scroll /*1px -109px*/ center transparent; 
   display: block; 
   width:inherit; height:24px; text-align:center; 
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 15%; 
   margin-bottom: 15%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Test Page](http://jsfiddle.net/zM5SG/4/)

I suggested to you to use `<img>` tag instead of `<span class="test">`, and I used `transform` css for scaling the image.

also `min-height` deleted for perfect working in all scales.

```
.test {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
-moz-transform: scale(0.2);
-o-transform: scale(0.2);
transform: scale(0.2);
}
```